# One obj-c function works fine in C callback, another does not when called exactly the same

Tags: objective-c, xcode, callback, multi-touch, iboutlet

I have an application that relies on a C callback method to retrieve multitouch information from a macbook's trackpad. Here's the truncated version of how I communicate this data to the user:

in MT2AppDelegate.h:

```
#import "MyView.h"
@interface MT2AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
        IBOutlet NSTextField *L1;
        IBOutlet MyView *MTView;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyView *MTView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSTextField *L1;
```

in MT2AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "etc. etc."
static MT2AppDelegate *sharedWithCAppDelegateReference;
@implementation MT2AppDelegate
@synthesize L1, MTView;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    sharedWithCAppDelegateReference=self;

    [L1 setStringValue:@"Hello"];//this works
        [MTView drawRect2];//this also works

    MTDeviceRef dev = MTDeviceCreateDefault();
    MTRegisterContactFrameCallback(dev, callback);
    MTDeviceStart(dev, 0);
}


int callback( int example, float etc) {

                [sharedWithCAppDelegateReference->L1 setStringValue:@"hello"];//this works 
                [sharedWithCAppDelegateReference->MTView drawRect2];//this does NOT work
        return 0;
}
```

So, for some reason, using a function on one IBOutlet works from C just fine, while another one does nothing. The same two functions both work in objective-c. I also cannot seem to call a function from the app delegate inside C. For example, `[sharedWithCAppDelegateReference setPoint];` does nothing.

Also, if there is a more elegant way to do this (I'm sure there is), I'm all ears. What is happening here is that this callback function is constantly updating, reporting the info about finger positions on the trackpad. I want to animate a view so that it gives a visual representation of finger location. The app FingerMgmt does a perfect job of this, but no source code is available.

I currently have my app delegate with the callback function inside it, and another class ("MyView") that is the class of the view in my application's window. The app delegate is linked to the view via an IBOutlet in interface builder, and I plan to pass commands to it to update the location of the ovals representing fingers. But again, this is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `->`;  totally not the standard Obj-C vibe.  Also, instance variables and properties should start with lowercase letters.

The underlying problem is that the callback API doesn't have a pointers worth of context.  Most callback APIs are defined like:

```
void fooBackMan(int a, float b, void *context);
```

Where you set 'em up something like:

```
extern set_up_callback(void(*callb)(int,float,void*), void*);
set_up_callback(&myCallbackFunc, someObject);
```

And, when the callback is called, the context pointer points to whatever thing you passed into the `set_up_callback()` function.  Typically, you would pass `self` or some other object as your context (retained first, of course) and then you could typecast and call methods on it like any other object.

Your callback doesn't do that and, thus, you need the global variable and your solution is pretty much inline with the expected behavior.  Save for the use of `->`.  Don't do that.

Instead, I'd define a method like `-handleMTCallbackWithExample:(int)anEx etc:(float)anEtc;` and then call that as the one line of code in my `callback()` func.

Comment: How odd, for some reason I was under the impression that `.` didn't work in old C. Thanks.    But I don't understand how your solution would work. I've tried making a method within my app delegate, and within the obj-c part of the app delegate, it's called as `[self setPoint]`. This works. However, when I call `[sharedWithCAppDelegateReference setPoint]` from the callback, nothing happens. For some reason, only functions from `L1` (an NSTextField) seem to work.